# What are the advantages of JSONPATH?

Tags: javascript, jsonpath

I'm currently working on a project I inherited from another developer that makes extensive use of JSONPATH to parse JavaScript objects.

Being a nodejs project, I find the use of JSONPATH to be obfuscating rather than enlightening.

I have been systematically removing it from the project whenever I find it in favor of straightforward maps, filters, reduce, etc, because they make the code easier for me to understand. But I wanted to know before I commit to removing it completely, if there's any advantage I may be missing. I also admit to have some reluctance to it as I never encountered it before.

I assume that JSONPATH can be very useful if:
A) you are unsure of the structure of the json data you're getting,
B) you are parsing DEEPLY nested objects which you may also need to flatten or
C) you are working on a language other than JavaScript.

But I don't feel either of this apply to my project. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

JSONpath becomes an advantage when your system needs to heavily manipulate json strings and get/filter only necessary data from it. We can avoid writing long and nested loops for the purpose of going through the json objects and json arrays. If your language that you are developing the system with, has JSONpath support then my advice would be to use it whenever and wherever you can.

And example usage is demonstrated here.

Let's say your json is like below.

```
{ "store": {
         "book": [ 
          { "category": "reference",
             "author": "Nigel Rees",
             "title": "Sayings of the Century",
             "price": 8.95
          },
          { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
          },
          { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
          },
          { "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
           }
         ],
        "bicycle": {
           "color": "red",
           "price": 19.95
         }
      }
    }
```

Here is a way you can manipulate and get details from the json.

```
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|               JSONPath                |                            Result                            |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| $.store.book[*].author                | the authors of all books in the store                        |
| $..author                             | all authors                                                  |
| $.store.*                             | all things in store, which are some books and a red bicycle. |
| $.store..price                        | the price of everything in the store.                        |
| $..book[2]                            | the third book                                               |
| $..book[(@.length-1)] or $..book[-1:] | the last book in order.                                      |
| $..book[0,1] or $..book[:2]           | the first two books                                          |
| $..book[?(@.isbn)]                    | filter all books with isbn number                            |
| $..book[?(@.price<10)]                | filter all books cheapier than 10                            |
| $..*                                  | all Elements in XML document. All members of JSON structure. |
+---------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Once you start using the JSONpath you will understand the flexibility and usefulness it gives you. Saves you time and code space.

Comment: Is `$.store.book[*].author` that much convenient than `store.book.map(x => x.author);` ?

I guess the level of nesting at which this becomes a real advantage is too deep to add to a SO answer. Still, thanks for your answer!